# How to use android-ndk?

Tags: android, c++, compiler-errors, android-ndk

I use PTAM code taken from [here](https://github.com/BeLioN-github/PTAM). I try to make an android application with this code.

The PTAM code uses libcvd, TooN, gvars3 library. I generate a .so file from my c++ test file using `ndk-build`.

Firstly, I try to run below code on android phone :

```
#include <string.h>
#include <jni.h>

extern "C" {

    int returnInt()
    {

        int returnVal = 4;
        return returnVal;
    }
}
```

It can generate .so file without any errors. If I add     `#include < TooN/TooN.h >` , `ndk-build says that

```
fatal error: TooN/TooN.h: No such file or directory
 #include <TooN/TooN.h>
                       ^
compilation terminated.
```

Android.mk is :

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := test-jni
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := test-jni.cpp

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

How can I solve this error message?

Comment: You need to add the parent directory of Toon to your include path. In your Android.mk, add the line `LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += the/path/to/Toon's/parent/directory`

Comment: I add `LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := /usr/include/TooN` to android.mk file. But the error exist still.

Comment: You shouldn't add the TooN directory itself, but its _parent_ directory (since you're also specifying the directory in `#include <>`).

Comment: You are rgiht. `LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := /usr/include` is enough. But `Toon.h` contains `#include <iostream>`. I get fatal error: iostream: No such file or directory.There is no folder named iostream under usr/include or usr/local/include.

Comment: Add `APP_STL := gnustl_shared` (or whichever STL-implementation you want to use) in your Application.mk

Comment: Thank you. If you add an answer this solution, I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> fatal error: TooN/TooN.h: No such file or directory
>    #include <TooN/TooN.h>

When you use `<>` with `#include`, the compiler will search for the file in your include path (and possibly other predefined directories).

To add a directory to your include path when building a module in `Android.mk` you would add it to `LOCAL__INCLUDES`. For example, if the full path to `TooN.h` is `/home/foobar/TooN/TooN.h` you should do this:

```
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += /home/foobar
```

---

> I get fatal error: iostream: No such file or directory.There is no folder named iostream under usr/include or usr/local/include.

The `iostream` class is part of the STL, so you need to specify an STL implementation to build against. This can be done using the `APP_STL` variable in `Application.mk`. For example:

```
APP_STL := gnustl_shared
```

See [this page](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpp-support.html) for a list of STL implementations available with the NDK.